# how to store data in NSmutable array from server

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I am trying to store data from server to NSMutable array to display them as news feeds in table view like shown in this [image](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-IcPZhG4Imj4/TxfN50V9DVI/AAAAAAAAAL4/gC716w_Npjk/s1600/twitter-pull-down-refresh-xcode.gif). Basically like twitter news feeds. What I wanna do is get the data from the server in the NSMutable array and use that array to display in my table view. I don't know if this is the right way to do it. I tried adding statically and it works but I really don't know how to do it dynamically since I'm a newbie to Objective C. Sorry if this question seems really stupid. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The data from the server come in JSON format or XML?

Comment: the data from the server comes in JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse data using JSON:

```
dispatch_queue_t jsonParsingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("jsonParsingQueue", NULL);

// execute a task on that queue asynchronously
dispatch_async(jsonParsingQueue, ^{
    NSString *urlStr = @"YourURL";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL: url];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData * jsonData = [responseStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableArray *tempResults = [NSMutableArray alloc];
    NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
    NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
    tempResults = jsonObject[@"posts"]; //Add the json key you would like to get

    self.arrayToDisplay = [tempResults copy]; //copy them to your NSMutableArray


    // some code on a main thread (delegates, notifications, UI updates...)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self.myTableView reloadData];


    });
});
```